# Select com filtro no entity sendo gerado duplicado

Tags: c#, ajax, entity-framework

Tenho um droplist que lista os estados, que quando é selecionado um estado ele filtra as cidades referentes a aquele estado. Acontece que quando eu seleciono as cidades vem duplicado.

Por exemplo, tenho os estados no select que são `São Paulo, Minas Gerais e Espirito Santo`, quando eu seleciono Minas Gerais por exemplo, ele aciona uma ajax para consumir as cidades que existem para aquele estado. Se eu selecionar Minas Gerais, teria que aparecer Apenas, `Belo Horizonte, Betim, Contagem` , acontece que aparece  `Belo Horizonte, Betim, Contagem, Belo Horizonte, Betim, Contagem` de forma duplicada.

Analisando o retorno da query que o entity monta, ficou algo assim

```
SELECT 

    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Nome] AS [Nome]
    FROM [dbo].[Cidade] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[UfId] = 'MG') OR (([Extent1].[UfId] IS NULL) AND ('MG' IS NULL))
```

que realmente trás os dados duplicados.

O problema é que não entendo o porque o entity está gerando a query desse jeito.

Segue minha função do entity

```
  [WebMethod]
  [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
  public JsonResult buscarCidades()
  {
     string estado = Request.QueryString["estado"];
     var cidades = db.Cidade.Where(e => e.UfId == estado).Select(c => new { c.Id, c.Nome });

    return Json(cidades, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

Obrigado desde já

Answer (score 1):

Quando acontecem registo duplicados, tenta sempre usar o `distinct` na query em que fazes a pesquisa. Normalmente funciona.

```
SELECT DISTINCT

[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Nome] AS [Nome]
FROM [dbo].[Cidade] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[UfId] = 'MG') OR (([Extent1].[UfId] IS NULL) AND ('MG' IS NULL))
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou colocar um distinct no entity e verei se dá